Negative offset voltage on analog input in data acquisition device (DAQ) connected to a photodiode in the dark
I have a data acquisition device (DAQ): USB-6002 from National Instruments (NI). I am recording an analog voltage from a (cathode-grounded) photodiode through a variable resistance (50-100k Ohms).
I noticed that in complete darkness, the measured signal from the photodiode sits around -0.0016V independent of the resistance value and bias voltage. I am not sure if this is relevant, but if I unplug the photodiode signal from the DAQ, the measured voltage oscillates close to 0V (slightly negative) with a larger amplitude (around 0.2V).
If I assume this negative offset is also present during my measurements, I can measure this continuous offset before hand and perform a background subtraction. However, I would like to understand the underlying electrical principles behind this behavior, to be confident that the background subtraction is the correct way to address this issue.
Why is there this seemingly small continuous voltage from the photodiode?

This is a schematic of the situation, I am using BNC cables in general with SMA-BNC adapters.

The manual of the DC bias module, which can be found in the PBM42 manual on the THORLABS website, has the following figure in it for reference (Fig. 4, page 12).


A schematic please.

@Andy aka, thank you for your input. I made a schematic that I hope will help clarify the situation.

No, that's a block diagram. If you don't have the detail inside each block it's impossible to suggest why this happens without guessing.

@Andy aka, is there some specs from those devices that I can give that would be helpful? I don't really want to open this equipment as it probably voids the warranty. THORLABS has a circuit diagram for the DC bias module that I will upload to my question as well.

Are you really connecting analog output 0 to the circuit? If so how, and what signal are you driving from that output?

@user1850479 I am using AO0 as the bias voltage for PBM42 (between A and B in the circuit diagram), but as I said, the DC offset on the photodiode signal is there even if I disconnect AO0. When you buy PBM42, they give you a cable with two pins for the DAQ side and a sort of jack which plugs into PBM42. When I am using it, I output a constant voltage from the DAQ. I haven't needed it so far to be honest, I just wanted to say it is there in case it matters.

OP's block diagram seems to set up the DAQ for a differential voltage measurement since AI0 and AI1 are active. It is unclear where AI0 is connected??
It might be better to set up the DAQ for a single-ended voltage measurement instead, so that the voltage across the load resistor of VT2 is measured.


how did you know my AI0 was also active? I'm using it for measuring another instrument, can it cause the offset? When I put the shield of the BNC cable after VT2 in a AGND pin, the DAQ measures a 50Hz signal with an amplitude of about 0.2V in the dark.

Was unclear from your block diagram where AI0 got its input. Had assumed (wrongly) that DAQ might be doing a differential measurement. Do you measure that large 50Hz signal with VT2 connected to DAQ, but disconnected from PBM42? At what resistance is VT2 set?

The 50Hz signal was measured with everything connected and VT2 at 1k Ohms. What difference does it make if I connect the BNC shield to AGND instead of the negative pin of AI0?

0.2V of 50 Hz across 1k is a very significant noise voltage that should be easy to track down. You must be careful about coax shields on that PBM42...we normally assume that they are GND but that's dangerous here. One coax side is GND, while the other side has shield connected to the DC bias. You're correct to be worried about a DC voltage across VT2's 1k resistor in the dark. A test: try 0V bias by shorting terminals A&B of PBM42's bias jack and see if you still measure DC offset and still see 50 Hz noise.

I'm starting to be confused. This is what I did. I put my photodiode into the 1k variable resistance and measured the signal on an oscilloscope. It gives me a near zero signal (dozens of uV mean value, and 1mV peak-to-peak). Then, I added PBM42, and the signal remains the same, irrespective of whether I short A&B. If I don't have anything at all connected to my DAQ the signal is quite random and around 60mV. If I use a small (2cm-long) cable to short the + and - terminals of AI1, I get this signal at -0.0016V again.

I will ask National Instrument because I now feel it is a DAQ issue really. I will update this post if I hear anything useful.
